# How do I split Strings (in Java) at any " character, but never at \"? Would RegEx be appropriate, and if, how?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need to split Java Strings at any " character.
The main thing is, the previous character to that may not be a backslash ( \ ).

So these Strings would split like so:

```
asdnaoe"asduwd"adfdgb         =>   asdnaoe, asduwd, adfgfb
addfgmmnp"fd asd\"das"fsfk    =>   addfgmmnp, fd asd\"das, fsfk
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this using regular expressions?
(I use RegEx because it is easiest for me, the coder. Also performance is not an issue...)

Thank you in advance.

I solved it like this:

```
    private static String[] split(String s) {
    char[] cs = s.toCharArray();

    int n = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        if (cs[i] == '"') {
            int sn = 0;

            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (cs[j] == '\\')
                    sn += 1;
                else
                    break;
            }

            if (sn % 2 == 0)
                n += 1;
        }
    }

    String[] result = new String[n];

    int lastBreakPos = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        if (cs[i] == '"') {
            int sn = 0;

            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (cs[j] == '\\')
                    sn += 1;
                else
                    break;
            }

            if (sn % 2 == 0) {
                char[] splitcs = new char[i - lastBreakPos];

                System.arraycopy(cs, lastBreakPos, splitcs, 0, i - lastBreakPos);
                lastBreakPos = i + 1;

                result[index] = new StringBuilder().append(splitcs).toString();
                index += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    char[] splitcs = new char[cs.length - (lastBreakPos + 1)];

    System.arraycopy(cs, lastBreakPos, splitcs, 0, cs.length - (lastBreakPos + 1));

    result[index] = new StringBuilder().append(splitcs).toString();

    return result;
}
```

Anyways, thanks for all your great responses!
(Oh, and despite this, I will be using either @biziclop's or @Alan Moore's version, as they
're shorter and probably more efficient! =)

Comment: I'm thinking some kind of negative lookbehind for a backslash?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Isn't that the same as a lookahead? :)

Comment: "Negative lookbehind" says that you should look behind and _not_ see something, not that you're looking behind a negative number of characters.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I know, it just struck me how funny it actually sounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use

```
(?<!\\)"
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> 'addfgmmnp"fd asd\"das"fsfk' -split '(?<!\\)"'
addfgmmnp
fd asd\"das
fsfk
```

However, this won't split on `\\"` (an escaped backslash, followed by a normal quote [at least in most C-like languages' escaping rules]). You cannot really solve that in Java, though, as arbitrary-length lookbehind isn't supported:

```
PS> 'addfgmmnp"fd asd\\"das"fsfk' -split '(?<!\\)"'
addfgmmnp
fd asd\\"das
fsfk
```

Usually you would expect a proper solution to split on the remaining `"` because it isn't really escaped.

Comment: I'm really not seeing how this _doesn't_ work in all cases.  Have you tested it on the case you claim fails?

Comment: This could work as a temporary solution. So thanks! But would there be any easy (?) way to implement this maybe not using RegEx then?

Comment: @TomS Of course, by writing your own little state machine (you'd have three or four states) and reading character by character. It's quite simple really..

Comment: I tested your expression in Regexplanet (http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) and it worked just fine.

Comment: The regex does what is says on the tin, i.e. it splits on quotation marks if they are not preceded by a backslash. I just added the caveat that if they use it to parse quoted strings that may contain escaped *backslashes* too, it will not do what they want.

Comment: But wouldn't something like this solve the problem of escaped backslashes? ((?<!\\\)")|((?<=\\\\\)") I'm not an expert, I haven't tested this...

Comment: Just tested it. Well, i guess you would somehow have to count the backslashes before any " and see if they're dividable by 2. Would that work in any particular way?

Comment: Not in a lookbehind. Not in Java at least.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem with a Java regex; just don't use `split()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  String[] strs = {
      "asdnaoe\"asduwd\"adfdgb",
      "addfgmmnp\"fd asd\\\"das\"fsfk"
  };

  for (String str : strs)
  {
    System.out.printf("%n%-28s=>  %s%n", str, splitIt(str));
  }
} 


public static List<String> splitIt(String s)
{
  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)+").matcher(s);
  while (m.find())
  {
    result.add(m.group());
  }
  return result;
}
```

output:

```
asdnaoe"asduwd"adfdgb       => [asdnaoe, asduwd, adfdgb]

addfgmmnp"fd asd\"das"fsfk  => [addfgmmnp, fd asd\"das, fsfk]
```

The core regex, `[^"\\]|\\.`, consumes anything that's not a backslash or a quotation mark, or a backslash followed by anything--so `\\\"` would be matched as an escaped backslash  (`\\`) followed by an escaped quote (`\"`).

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, here's a non-regexp solution that handles escaping of `\` as well. (In real life, this could be simplified, there's no real need for the `START_NEW` state, but I tried to write it in a way that's easier to read.)

```
public class Splitter {

    private enum State {
        IN_TEXT, ESCAPING, START_NEW;
    }

    public static List<String> split( String source ) {
        LinkedList<String> ret = new LinkedList<String>();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        State state = State.START_NEW;
        for( int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++ ) {
            char next = source.charAt( i );
            if( next == '\\' && state != State.ESCAPING ) {
                state = State.ESCAPING;
            } else if( next == '\\' && state == State.ESCAPING ) {
                state = State.IN_TEXT;
            } else if( next == '"' && state != State.ESCAPING ) {
                ret.add( sb.toString() );
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                state = State.START_NEW;
            } else {
                state = State.IN_TEXT;
            }
            if( state != State.START_NEW ) {
                  sb.append( next );
            }
        }
        ret.add( sb.toString() );
        return ret;
    }

}
```